# How can I make this Java Code Faster?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, arraylist

this code works fine, but it is too slow for where I am submitting it...

I am doing the Australian Informatics Competion and this code has to run under 0.5 seconds.
It is taking 0.4 for some questions and is correct, but it times out otherwise which is crap!
Is there a way of making it faster??
Plzz

Here it is:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("encyin.txt"));
    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("encyout.txt"));

    int length = input.nextInt();
    int questions_length = input.nextInt();

    ArrayList<Integer> page_words = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> questions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while(input.hasNextInt() && page_words.size() < length) {
        page_words.add(input.nextInt());
    }

    while(input.hasNextInt() && questions.size() < questions_length) {
        questions.add(input.nextInt()-1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<questions.size(); i++) {
        output.write(String.valueOf(page_words.get(questions.get(i))+"\n"));
    }

    input.close();
    output.close();

}


}
```

Thanks guys :)

Comment: You'll probably want to check with code review.

Comment: Hint:  how many times do you need to iterate with the same condition (`input.hasNextInt()`)?  You'd *likely* do better with one loop instead of two.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving the speed of working code, which is likely more suited for Code Review.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should pre-size your arraylists instead of letting them grow automatically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use two threads in a producer/consumer model, but this only helps if you're not IO-bound. And even if you're not IO-bound, if it's a single disk with high seek times, you could make things worse.

But really, you're probably IO-bound. Scanner might also not be using buffered IO.